# Interpreting Support Vector Machine Training file. How to calcute confidence after SVM.predict?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

How to calcute confidence after SVM.predict?

```
%YAML:1.0
my_svm: !!opencv-ml-svm
svm_type: EPS_SVR
kernel: { type:LINEAR }
C: 1.0000000000000001e-001
p: 1.0000000000000001e-001
term_criteria: { epsilon:9.9999999747524271e-007, iterations:1000 }
var_all: 10000
var_count: 10000
sv_total: 1
support_vectors:
  - [ 1.55572503e-004, 1.84632663e-004, 4.96124958e-005,
      -2.17121196e-005, -2.92743789e-005, 7.10865497e-005,
      9.92513524e-005, 3.12738739e-005, 1.05619969e-004,
      1.52145614e-004, 6.48323912e-005, 1.48814761e-005,
      2.78663483e-005, -4.44514626e-005, -1.67053367e-004,
      -2.43851537e-006, -1.06875894e-004, -3.03472800e-004,
      -3.82891594e-004 ]
decision_functions:
  -
     sv_count: 1
     rho: -1.4309503841001982e+001
     alpha: [ 1. ]
```

Answer (score 0):

SVMs in OpenCV won't give you a confidence for a prediction. Maybe you would try [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) on C++ combined with OpenCV.

Since you have only one support vector after your training, you may also try calculate the confidence yourself.

(1) w = alpha*yn*xn where xn is the support vector in your training output file,

(2) yn*(w'*xn+b) = 1 to solve b.

(3) with your test samples x_new, svm.predict gives you the classification(+ or - 1) computed as sign(w·x + b).Get confidence just by looking at |w·x+b|. Any value bigger than 1 means the SVM is reasonably sure about that point, and any value smaller means it isn't.